# Installing compile samples 4.0 failed nvidia

Tags: android, linux, 64-bit, nvidia

While installing NVidia Android CodeWorks I have received an error at the very end of the installation process saying :

```
installing compile samples 4.0 failed nvidia
Return Code: 2Compile Samples failed. Please check the /home/user/NVPACK//_installer/compile.log. You can send it to TegraDeveloperPack-Users@nvidia.com if you can not resolve it.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem please

Answer (score 0):

So that other people having the same problem might go on something for I have not found an optimal solution to this problem.
I have managed to solve it by simply copying my version of jdk (which is jdk1.8.0_101) to the specified Nvidia Codeworks folder and renaming to the one missing in the log (...\Nvidia\Codeworks_installer\compile.log - \Nvidia\Codeworks\jdk1.8.0_77" does not exist.) In my case it compiled successfully, however it must be noted that this is not a good solution. Messing around with the environment valuables might be a reasonable place to start otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

If your log file shows:

> Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
>      make: *** [antbuild_Basic_debug] Error 1
>       We cannot execute /usr/bin/java
>     Makefile.Basic.mk:92: recipe for target 'antbuild_Basic_debug' failed

you can fix it by creating a *soft* link like this:

```
sudo ln -s $JAVA_HOME/bin/java /usr/bin/java
```